# mongodb $where with another indexed field

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose, mongodb-query

Mongodb doc says `$where` does a collection scan, which is bad, but if I **add an indexed field in the query**, will that take advantage of indexed speed?

```
db.users.find({
   _id: someMongodbId, 
   $where: function() { return this.name == 'joe' } // ensure this doc has name "joe"
});
```

In the example above, there's only 1 query because of `_id` field, right?

Comment: Yes. Of course it does. The only part the `$where` is applied to is anything that was returned from results that "could" use an index. In this case, evaluating whether the found "document" actually matches the JavaScript condition "as well". So it will not "force" a collection scan and work the other way around if that is what you are asking. Of course you could just use `.explain()` and find that out yourself.

Comment: Actually quoted in the documentation of [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) *"In general, you should use $where only when you can’t express your query using another operator. If you must use $where, **try to include at least one other standard query operator to filter the result set**. Using $where alone requires a collection scan."*

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks